# Do Windows Modern Apps support CSS shaders?

Tags: css, windows-8, microsoft-metro

Can I use CSS3 shaders in Windows 8 Metro/modern UI apps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By CSS3 shaders I guess you mean the custom filters from CSS Filter Effects draft. As IE10 is the only browser for Modern apps, [not even the stock effects are supported](http://caniuse.com/css-filters). In fact AFAIK, the shaders (and regular filters) are only supported in recent WebKit, and it's highly experimental as well as prefixed. The standard is also still moving and Microsoft is making all efforts to not standardize the current recommendation of using GLSL as the shading language.

Worth noting is that Microsoft does have its own older, incompatible [filters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms530752%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).